# Conda environment is not used for installing packages

Tags: python, package, conda, jupyter, environment

I have created a env with

```
conda create --name llm_pdf
```

then deactivated base:

```
conda deactivate base
```

activated llm_pdf:

```
conda activate llm_pdf

conda list
```

shows no installed packages. Then I start a jupyter notebook from this anaconda shell.
I check the env in the notebook:

```
print(os.environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV'])
```

llm_pdf

Then the notbook installs quite a few packages:

```
!pip install langchain
_ = !pip install unstructured
....
```

This returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: langchain in d:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (0.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy<3,>=1.4 in d:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from langchain) (2.0.25)
```

When I check

```
conda list
```

there are no packages installed in my llm_pdf env.

What am I doing wrong? I need a clean environment into which all packages are installed, because with base I get errors during the installation.

Comment: If you run `!which pip` in a notebook you should see what python is being used. As you've not added any packages (including python) to the `llm_pdf` environment there should be nothing there for it to use

Comment: you are still running your jupyter notebook in your base conda environment. There is nothing in your environment, no jupyter-kernel, no python, no pip, so you also cannot `pip install` to it. Also notice that the path in your output `Requirement already satisfied: langchain in d:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (0.1.1)` is that of the base env, not your created env

Comment: To fix, install python and jupyter kernels to your env, register the kernel. Then start your notebook and select the correct kernel.